# Offset commit failed on partition

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Kafka consumer continues to print error messages

I built a cluster (kafka version 2.3.0) using 5 machines kafka, which has a partition with a partition of 0 and a data copy of 3. When I consume the kafka-clients api, I continue to output exceptions:
Offset commit failed on partition test-0 at offset 1: The request timed out.
But this topic reads and writes messages are fine.

Consumer configuration:

```
Auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
Auto.offset.reset = latest
Bootstrap.servers = [qs-kfk-01:9092, qs-kfk-02:9092, qs-kfk-03:9092, qs-kfk-04:9092, qs-kfk-05:9092]
Check.crcs = true
Client.id =
Connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
Default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
Enable.auto.commit = true
Exclude.internal.topics = true
Fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
Fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
Fetch.min.bytes = 1
Group.id = erp-sales
Heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
Interceptor.classes = []
Internal.leave.group.on.close = true
Isolation.level = read_uncommitted
Key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
Max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
Max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
Max.poll.records = 500
Metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
Metric.reporters = []
Metrics.num.samples = 2
Metrics.recording.level = INFO
Metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
Partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
Receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
Reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
Reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
Request.timeout.ms = 30000
Retry.backoff.ms = 100
Sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
Sasl.jaas.config = null
Sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
Sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
Sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
Sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
Sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
Sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
Sasl.login.class = null
Sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
Sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
Sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
Sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
Sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
Security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
Send.buffer.bytes = 131072
Session.timeout.ms = 10000
Ssl.cipher.suites = null
Ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
Ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
Ssl.key.password = null
Ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
Ssl.keystore.location = null
Ssl.keystore.password = null
Ssl.keystore.type = JKS
Ssl.protocol = TLS
Ssl.provider = null
Ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
Ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
Ssl.truststore.location = null
Ssl.truststore.password = null
Ssl.truststore.type = JKS
Value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
```

java code:

```
ConsumerRecords<K, V> consumerRecords = _kafkaConsumer.poll(50L);
for (ConsumerRecord<K, V> record : consumerRecords.records(topic)) {
    kafkaConsumer.receive(topic, record.key(), record.value(), record.partition(), record.offset());
}
```

I have tried the following:

1. Increase request timeout to 5 minutes (not working)
2. Replaced another group-id (it work): I found that as long as I use this group-id, there will be problems.
3. Kill the machine where the group coordinator is located. After the group coordinator switches to another machine, the error remains.

I get continuous error message output in the console

```
2019-11-03 16:21:11.687 DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=erp-sales] Sending asynchronous auto-commit of offsets {test-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=1, metadata=''}}
2019-11-03 16:21:11.704 ERROR org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=erp-sales] Offset commit failed on partition test-0 at offset 1: The request timed out.
2019-11-03 16:21:11.704 INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=erp-sales] Group coordinator qs-kfk-04:9092 (id: 2147483643 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
2019-11-03 16:21:11.705 DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=erp-sales] Asynchronous auto-commit of offsets {test-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=1, metadata=''}} failed due to retriable error: {}
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RetriableCommitFailedException: Offset commit failed with a retriable exception. You should retry committing the latest consumed offsets.
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: The request timed out.
2019-11-03 16:21:11.708 DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=erp-sales] Manually disconnected from 2147483643. Removed requests: OFFSET_COMMIT.
2019-11-03 16:21:11.708 DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=erp-sales] Cancelled request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=OFFSET_COMMIT, apiVersion=4, clientId=consumer-1, correlationId=42) due to node 2147483643 being disconnected
2019-11-03 16:21:11.708 DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=erp-sales] Asynchronous auto-commit of offsets {test-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=1, metadata=''}} failed due to retriable error: {}
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RetriableCommitFailedException: Offset commit failed with a retriable exception. You should retry committing the latest consumed offsets.
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException: null
```

1. Why did the submission of the offset fail?
2. Why is the offset information in the kafka cluster still correct when the submission fails?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Group coordinator Unavailability is the main cause of this issue.

**Group coordinator is Unavailable --**
    This issue is already raised in the KAFKA Community ([KAFKA-7017](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7017)).
    You can fix this by deleting the topic _offset_topics and restart the cluster.

You can go through the following to get few more details.
https://www.stuckintheloop.com/posts/my_first_kafka_outage/

Answer (score -1):

@Rohit Yadav, Thanks for the answer, I have replaced a consumer group for the time being and I am working very well. But now the client has another problem, continuous output:

```
2019-11-05 14:11:14.892 INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=fs-sales-be] Error sending fetch request (sessionId=2035993355, epoch=1) to node 4: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException.
2019-11-05 14:11:14.892 INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=fs-sales-be] Error sending fetch request (sessionId=181175071, epoch=INITIAL) to node 5: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException.
```

What is this caused by this? 4, 5 node status is OK